# how to take the sheen off baked high gloss surface

Tags: repainting

I intend to paint my kitchen doors as they have faded into an almost cream colour I want to bring them back to brilliant white, however, as the kitchen doors are profiled sanding is not an option, and as the surfaces rejects any attempts of over painting, hence removing the sheen in order to create a surface key is imperative

Comment: You might be able to find a chemical etcher you could use (depending on the nature of the existing paint), but imo you'd probably juts be better off putting in the effort to sand it. Maybe a gentle sand-blasting would be effective and allow you to more easily get into intricate profile surfaces...

Comment: If it's a steel door with baked finish etching primers are available in rattle cans.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I use to prep surfaces is scotch bright pads. The green ones are what I use most often they conform to shapes and really take the sheen or gloss out with very little effort. They have red that is    Heavier or more corse or white that is finer but green works quite well for irregular surfaces.

Comment: Rightfully the high answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's wood, sanding is always an option if you want professional results. You can also use a paint remover. There are many on the market that are a gel and water based and can be used indoors. One that come to mind is Citristrip, see below. It can be applied and after a short time can be wiped or lightly scraped off to removing the old surface, eliminating the sanding you so dread.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They make products called liquid sandpaper or deglosser.  You would rub onto the surface of the item you want to take the sheen off of. These products will prep glossy surfaces so new paint will stick to it. It works on many coatings i.e. Enamel, latex, polyurethane etc... They work fairly good. You could also use a q-tip or small brush to get into tight areas or corners.

Answer (score 0):

Sanding is the best option, just takes time, patience and elbow grease.